# Почему Html.ActionLink ссылается на активный контроллер?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Есть следующая ссылка, которая находится в `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Домашняя страница", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "nav-link"})
```

Дело в том, что если я нахожусь в `Home/Index`, `Home/About` или ещё где-то в Home, нажимаю на ссылку, то я вижу `Home/Index`. Зато, если я перехожу по этой же ссылке, работая с другим контроллером, то эта ссылка отправит меня в `ControllerName/Index`, а не в `Home/Index`.

Почему ссылка ведёт меня не туда, куда ей указали и как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/dd505040(v=vs.118)

Вы используете не тот перегруженный вариант метода `ActionLink`:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText, string actionName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
```

с четырьмя параметрами, где название контроллера вообще не указывается, поэтому соотвeтcтвует контроллеру текущего запроса. А то, что Вы пишете третьим параметром, рассматривается как `object routeValues`.

Вам нужен вариант:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName,
    object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
```

который надо вызывать так:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Домашняя страница", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "nav-link"})
```